# What does this problem mean?

Tags: probability

I have this probability exercise from Grimmett and Welch, which states that

If $A_{1}, A_{2}, \dots , A_{m} \in \mathcal{F}$ and $k$ is positive integer, show that the set of points in $\Omega$ which belong to exactly $k$ of the $A_{i}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$.

where $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are sample and event spaces respectively. I am not asking anyone to solve this problem for me, I am simply asking what this problem means precisely.

Answer (score 0):

One way of reformualting this is: Show that $\{\omega: \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} I_{A_i}(\omega)=k\}$ belongs to $\mathcal F$. (Note that the sum here is $k$ precisely when $\omega$ belongs to $k$ of the sets $A_1,A_2,..,A_n$).

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. I have one more question about your answer. What is $I_{A_i}(\omega)$ exactly?

Comment: @sejin8642 $I_E(\omega)=1$ if $\omega \in E$ and $0$ if $\omega \notin E$. This is a standard notation in Probability Theory.

Comment: Thank you so much!!